# Cant parse the correct ID of a product to my database

Tags: php, database

i'm trying to parse the value of a textfield to my database.

The value inside my textfield is the ID of my product. When somebody presses the button "pin" it should send the value of the ID from that product to my database but the problem is it only sends value "5" because thats the first ID of my product list.

I do not know why it only takes the first value of my list of products.

When i look at the products on my page i can clearly see ID number 45 but even when i pin that product it sends value 5 to the database everytime.

I hope i'm not being too confusing.

Here is my php form and under that is the php page to send the data

```
 <form id="myForm" action="insert/insertip.php" method="post" style="float:right;">
<input type="text" name="id" value="'. $row['id'] .'">
 <input type="submit" value="Pin It" id="pin"></form>


 $id = $_POST['id'];
  $cookie = $_COOKIE['cookie'];
   if(mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO pins(pinner, id_product) VALUES ('$cookie', '$id')"))
    echo "successfully Inserted";
else
    echo "insertion failed";
```

EDIT: Ill try to explain i little bit better, I have a whole list of products that i get from my database. Every product has a button under it to "pin" it. When somebody pins a product i send the ID of that product and the cookie of the user to my database. Everything works well exept when i try to send the ID of the product to my "pins" table it only sends the ID of my first product from the product table.

I dont know another way to send the ID of the product to the "pins" table than inside a textfield.
Maybe inside a span or use jQuery to put the value of the ID inside a variable and convert that variable to a PHP variable to send that value or something.

I also tried to use another name than "id" but it stays the same..

Comment: Do all the products have a input type="text" with the name "id"?

Comment: This `value="'. $row['id'] .'"` needs to be echo'ed. Plus this `$id = $_POST['id'];` try using `$id = $_REQUEST['id'];` since you're fetching from DB.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` during development.

Comment: use Firbug or Google Chrome network tab to see the payload of Form. if its containing id value 45 then this maybe database fields length issue, keep it int(11) in mysql